# android auto sync mysql to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, crud

I'd like to update (synchronize) the local database (`sqlite`) on `Android` from `MySQL` or `SQL Server` (server side) automatically and in background after `CRUD` operations in database (server-side)

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do lists.

Comment: Switch to Couchbase Lite and use Couchbase Sync. Already does syncing for you.

Comment: I was already read this posts and i didn't found a solution for my case.